# How to create multiple report folders for parallel testng tests using extent cucumber adaptor 7 plugin

Tags: grasshopper

I am using system properties to set base folder name and date time pattern to generate the extent report using cucumber adopter 7 plugin

As I got to see all properties are declared under static block

I am using testng for cucumber configuration and run the tests using testng.xml file.

I am able to run the same scenarios on multiple environments like QA Dev PreProd at single compilation but report folders gets generated for one environment and pdf, spark reports are merged as a single file instead of creating multiple folders and reports based on environment

I want to run one scenario on multiple environments at same time by using Java main method instead of surefire plugin and generate the spark and pdf reports for each environment